# Qual a origem do verbo adestrar?

Tags: etimologia, verbos

**Adestrar:** verbo transitivo direto e pronominal.

Indica a ação de fazer com que um animal ou pessoa fique hábil para realizar uma determinada ação, trabalho etc.

Exemplos:

> O cão foi adestrado para obedecer seu dono. 
>   Os policiais foram adestrados(preparados) para a missão.

Ouvi dizer que o verbo **adestrar** nasceu na época em os canhotos eram discriminados. Por isso, os pais amarravam a mão esquerda dos filhos canhotos, para os tornarem destros.

É isso mesmo?

Qual a origem do verbo adestrar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo o [Aulete digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/adestrar) e o Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa ***adestrar*** vem de ***destro*** (o Aulete admite também a possibilidade de vir diretamente do latim ***addextare***, mas não consegui sequer confirmar que essa palavra tenha existido).

Segundo o [Aulete, ***Destro***](http://www.aulete.com.br/destro) significa, para além de (lado) direito, ou alguém que usa mais a mão direita,

> **3.** Dotado de especial habilidade; PERITO **4.** Fig. Que demonstra agilidade, desembaraço.

Portanto parece-me que *adestrar* terá provavelmente nascido da ideia de tornar alguém *destro* no sentido (3) do Aulete, *hábil, perito*. Note-se que este significado já estava presente no latim [***dexter***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dexter#Latin), que é a origem do português *destro*.

A primeira ocorrência de *destro* com o significado de *hábil* que encontrei no português foi na [*Crónica do Conde D. Pedro de Meneses*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=LWhJAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA344&lpg=PA344&dq=%22bem%20destro%20naquelle%20mester%22&source=bl&ots=chK2S_LxqZ&sig=2xZHbe25pafQStTg76EbWRFSWUs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid37TjxpfKAhVBshQKHfkZAWgQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22bem%20destro%20naquelle%20mester%22&f=false) de [Gomes Eanes de Zurara](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gomes_Eanes_de_Zurara), 1463:

> Diogo Vazquez hera homë bem ***destro*** naquelle mester & abastava-lhe o coraçam pera fazer quallquer cousa trabalhosa, por muito perigosa que fosse.

*Adestrar*, no sentido de treinar, ensinar, aparece em [*Saudades da Terra*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudades_da_Terra) de [Gaspar Frutuoso](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaspar_Frutuoso), escrito entre 1586 e 1590; a passagem inclui também *destros*:

> o recolheu em sua casa e mandou ensinar e ***adestrar*** nas ciencias e armas como filho, nas quais tanto aproveitou Filomesta em poucos anos, que os mais sobios nas ciencias daquela cidade lhe davam obediencia e os mais ***destros*** nas armas lhe reconheciam avantagem e o temiam

Nesta versão galaico-portuguesa da [Historia Xeral de 1300](http://sli.uvigo.es/xelmirez/xelmirez_contexto.php?idf=140147&idt=27&procura=(?:(?=[a-z%C3%A1%C3%A9%C3%AD%C3%B3%C3%BA%C3%A3%C3%B5%C3%B1%C3%A7%C3%BD])(?%3C![a-z%C3%A1%C3%A9%C3%AD%C3%B3%C3%BA%C3%A3%C3%B5%C3%B1%C3%A7%C3%BD])%7C(?%3C=[a-z%C3%A1%C3%A9%C3%AD%C3%B3%C3%BA%C3%A3%C3%B5%C3%B1%C3%A7%C3%BD])(?![a-z%C3%A1%C3%A9%C3%AD%C3%B3%C3%BA%C3%A3%C3%B5%C3%B1%C3%A7%C3%BD]))Pedro(?:(?=[a-z%C3%A1%C3%A9%C3%AD%C3%B3%C3%BA%C3%A3%C3%B5%C3%B1%C3%A7%C3%BD])(?%3C![a-z%C3%A1%C3%A9%C3%AD%C3%B3%C3%BA%C3%A3%C3%B5%C3%B1%C3%A7%C3%BD])%7C(?%3C=[a-z%C3%A1%C3%A9%C3%AD%C3%B3%C3%BA%C3%A3%C3%B5%C3%B1%C3%A7%C3%BD])(?![a-z%C3%A1%C3%A9%C3%AD%C3%B3%C3%BA%C3%A3%C3%B5%C3%B1%C3%A7%C3%BD]))&corpus=historico) atribuída a Afonso X, *adestrar* parece querer dizer *auxiliar, servir de braço direito*, neste caso a um cego:

> Lamec (...) que tanto viueo longa vida que perdeo o veer et foy çego et ouvo despoys hũ moço queo ***adestraua*** pero mãçebo, segũdo conta o Genesis queo moço o ***adestraua*** et oguyaua por onde ya.

Comment: Essa ideia parece a mais plausível: um dos sentidos do prefixo _a-_ «é o de "passagem a um estado"», segundo o [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-prefixo-a--em-bife-acebolado-ou-cinto-afivelado/21873).